# Time Picker ignores the number 0 before it

Tags: android, android-timepicker

This is my code:

```
break1 =(TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.break1);    
int hourb1 = break1.getCurrentHour();    
int minb1 = break1.getCurrentMinute();
```

The Time I get for `06:00` is `6:0` and for `06:08` is `6:8` could someone tell how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a '06' to an int...since int is a primitive it cannot take the form of a string thus 06 is simply a 6 08 is simply a 8 etc..
Just pad numbers smaller than 10 with a heading zero and save the result to a string and you'll be fine